# Similarity in tsv column

Tags: postgresql, similarity, self-join, tsvector

I'm needing some help getting the SQL to work here in PostgreSQL 9.5.1 using pgAdminIII. What I have is a column `status` (datatype, text) of Facebook statuses in the format they were typed and another column `status_tsv` which stores a tsvector of the status column with stop words removed and the words stemmed.

I'd like to find similar statuses by comparing the similarity of the tsvector column in a self-join.

Thus far I have tried using a regexp_replace function combined with the pg_trgm similarity search to keep only the a-zA-Z character set in the tsvector column but this didn't worked as regexp_replace says it can't do tsvector columns so I've changed datatype of tsv column to text.

The problem now is that it only compares the similarity of the first word in each row and ignores the rest, obviously this is no use and I need it to compare the whole row.

My SQL just now looks like

```
`SELECT * FROM status_table AS x
JOIN status_table AS y
ON ST_Dwithin (x.geom54032, y.geom54032,5000)
WHERE  status_similarity (x.tsvector_status, y.tsvector_status) > 0.7
AND x.status_id != y.status_id;`
```

The `status_similarity` does this `(regexp_replace(x.tsvector_status, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g'), regexp_replace(y.tsvector_status, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g')) which I'm sure keeps only the a-zA-Z from the tsvector_status column.

What must I changed to get this returning similar status'?